# Flask admin view List fields from two tables

Tags: postgresql, flask, cassandra, flask-admin

I have two models say, Post and View and those are in two different backends. Post is in `**Postgres**` db and View is in `**Cassandra**` db. View table has a column post_id, which is the id of the post in the Post table and it is a primary key. I want to list all fields in views table plus amount(which is a column in Post table) in the Flask admin page. How can I achieve this? I'm extending the `BaseModelView` to list the fields in View table

Comment: what you got so far?

Comment: Currently it solved by customizing the get_query() method. But now I'm stucked  with another issue, Datetime filter in admin page. Can you please have look into this
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36067581/datebetweenfilter-filter-is-not-working-in-flask-admin)