# DateBetweenFilter filter is not working in flask admin

Tags: filter, flask, cassandra, flask-admin

I created a custom `datetimefilter` in flask admin and it looks good(able to select the datetime range) in the UI, but not working in functionality. I think the apply method is not working. The table which i'm going to apply this filter is in `Cassandra`.

```
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla.filters import BaseSQLAFilter
from flask_admin.model import filters
class DateBetweenFilter(BaseSQLAFilter, filters.BaseDateBetweenFilter):
    def __init__(self, column, name, options=None, data_type=None):
        super(DateBetweenFilter, self).__init__(column,
                                                name,
                                                options,
                                                data_type='daterangepicker')

def apply(self, query, value, alias=None):
    start, end = value
    return query.filter(self.get_column(alias).between(start, end))
```

and the corresponding Admin class that uses the filter

```
class SearchAdminView(BaseModelView):
    column_filters = [
      DateBetweenFilter(
         Search.created_date, 'Created Date'
      )
    ]
```

what I'm missing?

Comment: There is a DateBetweenFilter class in flask_admin.contrib.sqla.filters, why you create your own ? please check http://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/flask_admin/contrib/sqla/filters/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may missed to add the code that invokes the apply() for the filters defined in the admin class in the get_list() method.

Try to add the below code in your get_list() method.

```
def get_list(self, page, sort_column, sort_desc, search, filters,
             execute=True, page_size=None):
    """
        Get list of objects
    """
    query = self.get_query(page, page_size)
    for flt, k, value in filters:
        query = self._filters[flt].apply(query, value, page_size)
```